# ScrollView allow content overflow

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

### Goal

I am trying to allow a `scrollview` to overflow (not clip its children). I have this working with a carousel view but cannot get the same result with a `scrollview`.

The idea of this is to center the `scrollview` and allow overflow so the content can look centered (being used as tabs).

---

### Code

Use of the `scrollview` in Xamarin Forms:

```
 var scrollView = new ScrollView
 {
    WidthRequest = 200,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
    Content = scrollViewContent,
    IsClippedToBounds = false
 };
```

This is my custom renderer for the `scrollview`:

```
public class CenteredScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        if (e.OldElement != null)
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;

        e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;


    }

    protected void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ChildCount > 0)
        {
            GetChildAt(0).HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            GetChildAt(0).VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            GetChildAt(0).OverScrollMode = OverScrollMode.Never;

            // Try and disable clip
            ((ViewGroup)GetChildAt(0)).SetClipToPadding(false);
            ((ViewGroup)GetChildAt(0)).SetClipChildren(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Other attempts

I have also created a function to go through **ALL** parents to disable clipping just to see if it was a parent causing a problem. This still has not worked.

So how do we allow the `scrollview` content to overflow outside of its bounds?

<sup>**Note:** I am tagging android as this could be a simple misunderstanding of the native control.</sup>

---

### Update:

Tried my best to make an image of the desired effect I am looking for. 
[image: ScrollView]

So the big blue border is the `scrollview` in the middle of the `contentview`. The scroll content is only visible when inside the `scrollview` itself (how it always works). I am trying to not clip the content so can always see all content (overflow), not just inside the `scrollview`.

---

### Update 2:

The following link may explain the effect I am after better then I have. Please take a look, any question let me know.

[Paging-enabled UIScrollView With Previews](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html)

**Note:** I have linked the touch events up so it is only disabling clipping bounds that I need to find a fix for.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve, could you please show an image? I don't understand how contents of `ScrollViewer` could be overflow, but do you need effect like fade in/ out  of `ScrollView`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thank you for your comment. I feel I may not have explained this well and have tried to create an update to give more information. If this doesn't seem to explain it I can make a project and give that to you. **Note:** I believe what I am trying to make Android already has as a Recycle view, using this you can center content and scroll (it locks on to a tile and centers always, like the play store). But I am trying to do this in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: If you can achieve it using `Recyclerview`, then in XF, you may try to use `ViewRenderer` for customizing.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT At the moment I have everything working as intended apart from this one last part. It should be simple to get this working as I have it working with 1 line of code for iOS (`v.ClipsToBounds = false;`). It would be a lot of work for next to no gain to try implement a `Recyclerview`.

Comment: Just tested in iOS, but sorry, I couldn't figure out any properties which can be set to `ScrollView` to achieve this in Android.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Ah, did you see what I mean? So iOS works fine but Android does not accept it. I tried to go through parents of the view to disable clipping with no luck but for other views (carousel view) it does work.

Comment: @Ruddy, I am not able to imagine the expected effect, is it possible to make a gif of what is expected?

Comment: @Dinash I have updated my answer with a link, if you take a look it should explain exacting what I am looking for (as this is the page that gave me the idea in the first place).

Comment: You could try the same approach as with elevation / shadow clipping. Add a parent layout, add padding to the parent layout (to achieve the `centered` item) and set `clipToPadding=false` in the parent layout.

Comment: @damian You sir get a cookie! Put that as an answer and I will accept. I never thought to do this! Thank you, for me this was a solution as I know the width when drawing the `scrollview` so I was able to set the padding and in my custom renderer still used `SetClipToPadding`. Again... great idea and works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the same approach as with elevation / shadow clipping.

Add a parent layout, add padding to the parent layout (to achieve the centered item) and set `clipToPadding=false` in the parent layout.

Since the question is about Xamarin, I'll just mention that for native Android development you could achieve the same center-locked effect with a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and an implementation of the [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html) class.

Comment: As for the second part of this answer, this was my backup plan. I had been reading its very hard to get the Recycler View working with Xamarin Forms. So this answer does the job I need it to do for now. Thanks again. I will award the bounty soon, see if anyone can better your answer! ;)